# setting @each property, proper use - splitting search results with EmberJs

Tags: ember.js, propertychanged

Im trying to split search results into bulks of 5 so each bulk could be presented desperately.

my data:

```
Wacky.Video = Ember.Object.extend({
    DATA: null
    presenter : null
});
```

The presenter holds the page number on which the data should appear - e.g model[0-5] hold val. 1, model[6-10] hold val. 2 and so on...

my controller:

```
Wacky.SearchController = Ember.Controller.extend({
...
resPageNum: 1,
...
```

This property will de/increment whenever a page number will be changed (by button click).

my HTML code:

```
{{#each res in model}}
    {{#if pagePresentor}}
        <div class="results">
            //DO STUFF WITH RES. OBJECT
        </div>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

finally "pagePresentor" is a property that needs to determine which bulk to present in the current iteration.

So far Iv got this:

```
pagePresentor: function(value){
    return value.presenter == this.get('resPageNum');
}.property('resPageNum','@each.presentor')
```

But I guess Im using it wrong, because nothing is getting printed at all.

Could anyone please explain how to set this working or at least the base principal for what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
pagePresentor: function(value){
    return value.presenter == this.get('resPageNum');
}.property('resPageNum','@each.presentor')
```

Here `@each.presentor` is a mistake. You should specify observed property which is in the array in the following format: `arrayName.@each.propertyName` according to http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/. So, here the name of array which contains the objects with `presentor` property is missing.